# How to do the classification and count of DataFrame columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to count consecutive `0`s, if there are `0`s, `count` the consecutive numbers, and assign the numbers to the `count` column, and if they encounter `1`, `recount`.

I also tried several methods, but none of them achieved my results.

An example of my Dataframe is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2021)
a = np.random.randint(0, 2, 20)
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['No.'])
print(df)
```

```
     No.
0     0
1     1
2     1
3     0
4     1
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     1
9     0
10    1
11    1
12    1
13    1
14    0
15    0
16    0
17    0
18    0
19    0
```

The result I need:

```
    No. count
0   0   1
1   1   0
2   1   0
3   0   1
4   1   0
5   0   3
6   0   3
7   0   3
8   1   0
9   0   1
10  1   0
11  1   0
12  1   0
13  1   0
14  0   6
15  0   6
16  0   6
17  0   6
18  0   6
19  0   6
```

I tried the following methods, but none of them achieved my results. What should I do?

```
groups = df['No.'].ne(0).cumsum()
```

```
df['count'] = df['No.'].eq(0).groupby(groups).count()
```

```
df['count'] = df['No.'].eq(0).groupby(groups).agg(len)
```

```
df['count'] = df['No.'].groupby(groups).agg(len)
```

```
df['count'] = df['No.'].groupby(groups).count()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder from @Ch3steR, I now finally found out how to find the problem more effectively in `starkoverflow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `groups` variable, calculate `diff` first, so you assign an `id` to each consecutive sequence that contains the same value. And to get the equal sized `count` Series that can be assigned to original data frame, use `transform` instead of `agg`:

```
df['count'] = 0
groups = df['No.'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
df.loc[df['No.'] == 0, 'count'] = df['No.'].groupby(groups).transform('size')
df

    No.  count
0     0      1
1     1      0
2     1      0
3     0      1
4     1      0
5     0      3
6     0      3
7     0      3
8     1      0
9     0      1
10    1      0
11    1      0
12    1      0
13    1      0
14    0      6
15    0      6
16    0      6
17    0      6
18    0      6
19    0      6
```